# SeaDragon Mouse Clicks

Tags: seadragon

How can I determine the location of a mouse click on an Ajax SeaDragon scene relative to the source image that was used to generate the DeepZoom content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to get your position on the scene in pixels or seadragon coordinates :

```
obj = new Seadragon.Viewer( targetId )
obj.viewer.tracker.pressHandler = function(tracker, position) {   
        console.log('pressHandler', position.x, position.y);
        obj.location = new Seadragon.Point(
                parseInt(position.x),
                parseInt(position.y)
        );  
       var pointPos = obj.view.viewport.pointFromPixel(obj.location);
};
```

hope this helps